# SQL Server Push Notifications to Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xamarin.forms, push-notification

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms app using SQL Server as the backend database, and I have a requirement that when one user inserts data, another user gets this data as a notification.

Note that the app is connected directly to the database without web service or any other Layer.

Can anyone tell me how to implement this feature?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I'd advise very strongly against a Xamarin.Forms app (or any mobile application, for that matter) connecting directly to database. Write an API to take care of that for you.

To answer your question though, you need to register the application with a push notification provider. On Android, the native provider is Firebase. On iOS, the native provider is Apple Push Notification Service - or APNS for short. However, you can also use Firebase for iOS via a Google supplied package - which Microsoft have released Xamarin bindings for.

Here's a pretty good video showing how to do that (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNBuaAB8nR8), it's quite current (uploaded in 2021) and the guy, as of the time of writing, works for Microsoft.

Once you've got that implemented, you're going to need some way to push a message from your database to Firebase. A simple API would be my suggestion. Firebase will then handle pushing that data down to your app, in the form of a push notification. You can have a read about the Firebase notification message schema here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Just to re-iterate what I said at the top. I'd **strongly** suggest that you **do not** connect directly to a database from a mobile app. Outside of the many security implications of doing that, there's many design challenges that you'll face with that approach if you ever need to scale the app up.

EDITED: Fixed a typo.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer sir.
First, for the notification question, I've heard that you can also do it by the App Center and if so, I'm wondering which is the best for this feature.
Second, on your advice on not to connect the app to DB Directly if you can mention any helpful video or article to help me understand the situation.